# Ruby On Rails High Volume API response Logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, database-design, error-logging

Scenario:
I would call a third party api and get response , considering the response size to be 40000 lines of xml. I want to store these response in case of any third party api failures , i can reuse the last recieved/stored response.

I have a confusion on what's the best way to store this response

My analyzed options are

1. Store in the error responses table in our db.With the following db maintenance

- rake to clear record older than 30 days
- Using an text column, my only concern is if the string is too large will it be an issue ? I won't read the logs that frequently , only for the case of recovery which is very rare.

2. Upload the responses to an an s3 bucket (Involves cost )
3. Cloud watch logs (Involves cost)

What db column type should be considered ? ( Is text good  , what kind of index if any?) Provided it is could be mysql or postgresql db.

From a cost perspective application db is best . I want some suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you've described is more accurately referred to as caching rather than logging. Of the options you've mentioned, I recommend storing the responses in the DB. Among the advantages of this approach over the others are:

- No significant additional cost.
- No additional external service dependencies.
- Less complex implementation.

Storing the response in a column of type `text` should be adequate; however, I recommend using the `XML` data type since it offers additional capabilities and could help protect against malformed responses. The PostgreSQL `text` and `XML` data types can store values up to ~1GB in size, so it is unlikely that the response size will be an issue.

There should be a unique index on the attributes that identify matching past responses. When a new response that matches a past response is received, the past response row is updated instead of inserting a new row. An efficient way of handling this in PostgreSQL is to use the `INSERT` command's `ON CONFLICT` clause. (If using PostgreSQL v15 or later, the `MERGE` command offers a more SQL standard approach than `INSERT` with `ON CONFLICT`.) While updating in this manner reduces the number of old rows, it doesn't eliminate them, so a mechanism to remove old (expired) rows will still be desirable.

Comment: It is not caching in my use case , i want to store the api response if it is the same as it was last time.redundant entries of same response is fine and it would be caching. My concern is i don't want to read and compare the response and just append the timestamp of every occurrence.  The chances of change in the response could be high ( as little as a different street address in one of the keys) 

Unique index would be problematic considering any node in xml can be changed and  cannot narrow down to 1 node . Any reasons you don't prefer s3 ? As far i read it is inexpensive for 30d.